# The process cannot access the file

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, io, cryptography, c++-cli

Please have a look at the following code

```
void InformationWriter::writeContacts(System::String ^phone, System::String ^email)
{
    try
    {
        //Write the file
        StreamWriter ^originalTextWriter = gcnew StreamWriter("contacts.dat",false);
        originalTextWriter->WriteLine(phone);
        originalTextWriter->WriteLine(email);
        originalTextWriter->Close();


        //Encrypt the file
        FileStream ^fileWriter = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::OpenOrCreate,FileAccess::Write);

        DESCryptoServiceProvider ^crypto = gcnew DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        crypto->Key = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes("Intru235");
        crypto->IV = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes("Intru235");

        CryptoStream ^cStream = gcnew CryptoStream(fileWriter,crypto->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);


        //array<System::Byte>^ phoneBytes = ASCIIEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(phone);
        FileStream ^input = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::Open); //Open the file to be encrypted
        int data = 0;

        while((data=input->ReadByte()!=-1))
        {
            cStream->WriteByte((System::Byte)data);
        }

        input->Close();
        cStream->Close();
        fileWriter->Close();

        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show("Data Saved");
    }
    catch (IOException ^e)
    {
        System::Windows::Forms::MessageBox::Show(e->Message);
    }


}
```

When the following part get executed, I get an error

```
FileStream ^input = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::Open); //Open the file to be encrypted
```

Below is the error I get

[image]

This is the first time I am using `CryptoStream` and I new to C++/CLI as well.

Comment: Your code is fundamentally flawed, it is not exception safe.  Google "c++/cli stack semantics" to learn how to write it properly.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks a lot for pointing out issues. I will check them out :)

Comment: Note that DES is just too weak. The ASCII key makes it even weaker. Using the key as the IV is very wrong too, and so is using a static IV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileStream ^fileWriter = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::OpenOrCreate,FileAccess::Write);

// snip

FileStream ^input = gcnew FileStream("contacts.dat",FileMode::Open); //Open the file to be encrypted
```

You're opening the file twice, once for input and once for output. You've got a few choices here:

1. Open the file with sharing enabled, allowing you to open it twice.
2. Open the file, read the entire file into memory, close the file, then open
   the file for output and do the encryption.
3. Open a temporary file for
   output, write all the data there, and then rename the temp file over
   top of the original file.

Comment: I used the 3rd method. Thanks a lot. Windows programming is new to me, because I am from Java, Android and C++